# xls download issue with jasper reports in php

Tags: php, jasper-reports, php-java-bridge

I have implemented jasper reports using version 6.3.1 in my application with php integration by using [This Link](https://github.com/tsuyu/jasper-report-php-integration/blob/master/generate.php)  And everything is working fine with this code and i can able to export pdf & csv files. But i am getting an issue while exporting xls file.

Code for Xls file Export

```
    try {
        $exporter = new java("net.sf.jasperreports.engine.export.JRXlsExporter");
        $exporter->setParameter(java("net.sf.jasperreports.engine.export.JRXlsExporterParameter")->IS_ONE_PAGE_PER_SHEET, java("java.lang.Boolean")->TRUE);
        $exporter->setParameter(java("net.sf.jasperreports.engine.export.JRXlsExporterParameter")->IS_WHITE_PAGE_BACKGROUND, java("java.lang.Boolean")->FALSE);
        $exporter->setParameter(java("net.sf.jasperreports.engine.export.JRXlsExporterParameter")->IS_REMOVE_EMPTY_SPACE_BETWEEN_ROWS, java("java.lang.Boolean")->TRUE);
        $exporter->setParameter(java("net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRExporterParameter")->JASPER_PRINT, $jasperPrint);
        $exporter->setParameter(java("net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRExporterParameter")->OUTPUT_FILE_NAME, $outputPath);
    } catch (JavaException $ex) {
        echo $ex;
    }
```

And it's throwing an exception like

HTTP Status 500 - java.lang.RuntimeException: PHP Fatal error: Uncaught [[o:Exception]:"java.lang.Exception: Invoke failed: [[i:JRExporter]]->exportReport. Cause: php.java.bridge.NoSuchProcedureException: static exportReport(). Candidates: [] VM: 1.7.0_121@http://java.oracle.com/" at:

Can anyone suggest me the solution for this exception And please suggest me that the package if anything is missing here to include.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

(Edited) From the exception message `[[i:JRExporter]]->exportReport`, you're actually not calling the `$exporter->exportReport()` method on the object you think (`net.sf.jasperreports.engine.export.JRXlsExporter`) but on the `net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRExporter`.

So it's not a problem of missing library, but probably a typo when you tested with the 'format' parameter (xls)...

---

a little explanation:

The `NoSuchProcedureException` thrown while invoking the exportReport() method indicates that it does not exists on the `$exporter` object.

Looking at the [JRXlsExporter api doc](http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/api/net/sf/jasperreports/engine/export/JRXlsAbstractExporter.html#exportReport()) the method is well present and should be usable.

So it seems very unlikely to me that the `NoSuchProcedureException` would be thrown calling `exportReport()` at least if...

...my guess, and I can be wrong, is that the `$exporter` object is not the one you think. If I look to the link you provided, the scenario could be possible, because `$exporter` is by default to `net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRExporter` (actually an [interface](http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/api/net/sf/jasperreports/engine/JRExporter.html))

If the `$_POST['format']` parameter is not **'xls'** (or any values covered in the switch), the previously set `$exporter` will be used. And in this case should not work by nature (JRExporter Interface)

See excerpt from your code snippet:

```
$exporter = new java("net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRExporter");
switch ($_POST['format']) {
    case 'xls':
        $outputPath = realpath(".") . "\\" . "output.xls";
        try {
            $exporter = new java("net.sf.jasperreports.engine.export.JRXlsExporter");
        $exporter->setParameter(java("net.sf.jasperreports.engine.export.JRXlsExporterParameter")->IS_ONE_PAGE_PER_SHEET, java("java.lang.Boolean")->TRUE);
        $exporter->setParameter(java("net.sf.jasperreports.engine.export.JRXlsExporterParameter")->IS_WHITE_PAGE_BACKGROUND, java("java.lang.Boolean")->FALSE);
        $exporter->setParameter(java("net.sf.jasperreports.engine.export.JRXlsExporterParameter")->IS_REMOVE_EMPTY_SPACE_BETWEEN_ROWS, java("java.lang.Boolean")->TRUE);
        $exporter->setParameter(java("net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRExporterParameter")->JASPER_PRINT, $jasperPrint);
        $exporter->setParameter(java("net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRExporterParameter")->OUTPUT_FILE_NAME, $outputPath);
    } catch (JavaException $ex) {
        echo $ex;
    }
    header("Content-type: application/vnd.ms-excel");
    header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=output.xls");
    break;
```

So my answer would be:

**Check that your $_POST['format'] really equals to 'xls' (not xslx, xsl...)**

If it was the problem, consider at least throwing a exception (unsupported format) in your switch 'default' section.

If it's not, please include more infos about your exception (stack trace), because It's quite short to make a guess